# Efficiency of Subselects Within a MySQL Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I am trying to produce a report from a collection of database tables, and I'm finding that the query I've written is super slow. I realise that using multiple subselects on a select query will increase the time the query will take to complete, because each row requires multiple subqueries to the database but what can I do to make my query faster and more efficient?

I've tried wrapping this in a prepared statement and it has little effect, Is there a way that I'm missing that would allow the extraction of the needed information faster?

```
SELECT Contractor.id,
Contractor.Unique_ID,
Contractor.FName,
Contractor.SName,
Contractor.MIName,
Contractor.NI_Number,
Contractor.Address,
Contractor.Phone_Main,
Contractor.Phone_Mobile,
Contractor.Email,
Contractor.Bank_Name,
Contractor.Bank_Account_Name,
Contractor.Bank_Account_Sort_Code,
Contractor.Bank_Account_Number,
Contractor.DOB,
Contractors.DateTime_Account_Created,
Contractor.Payment_Frequency,
Contractor.Saving_Tax_Pref,
Contractor.Holiday_Savings_Pref,
Contractor.UTR,
Contractor.DateTime_Last_Logged_In,
Contractor.Leaving_Date,
Agency.Name,
(
    SELECT ROUND(SUM(ContractorSavings.value - ContractorSavings.paidOutValue), 2)
    FROM ContractorSavings
    LEFT JOIN SavingsToPayJunction ON SavingsToPayJunction.SavingsId = ContractorSavings.id
    WHERE fullyPaid = 0
    AND ContractorSavings.type_id = 2
    AND SavingsToPayJunction.ContractorId = Contractor.id
) AS 'Tax_Saving_Balance',
(
    SELECT ROUND(SUM(ContractorSavings.value - ContractorSavings.paidOutValue), 2)
    FROM ContractorSavings
    LEFT JOIN SavingsToPayJunction ON SavingsToPayJunction.SavingsId = ContractorSavings.id
    WHERE fullyPaid = 0
    AND ContractorSavings.type_id = 2
    AND SavingsToPayJunction.ContractorId = Contractor.id
) AS 'Holiday_Saving_Balance',
(
    SELECT ROUND(SUM(Expense_Value),2)
    FROM Contractor_Expenses
    WHERE Contractor_ID = Contractor.id
    AND authorised = 0
)AS 'Expenses_Claimed',
(
    SELECT ROUND(SUM(Expense_Value - amountAllocated),2)
    FROM Contractor_Expenses
    WHERE Contractor_ID = Contractor.id
    AND authorised = 1
    AND fullyAllocated = 0
)AS 'Expenses_Authorised',
(
    SELECT MAX(Contractor_Pay.Date_Earned)
    FROM Contractor_Pay
    WHERE Contractor_Pay.Contractor_ID = Contractor.Unique_ID
)AS 'Last_Pay_Date'
FROM Contractor
LEFT JOIN Agency ON Agency.id = Contractor.Agency_ID
```

Apologies for the unwieldy query dump. I look forward to your responses.

Thank you,

*** POST ANSWER EDIT ***

For those that care about timings and the like, the answer reduced my query time down from in excess of 3:00 minutes down to 45 seconds.

Comment: you're using corelated subqueries. for EVERY row in your main query, you'll also be running those subqueries. so for an `n` row `contractor` table, you'll actually be running. `1+(n*6)` queries. e.g. 1000 contractor rows, 6001 queries executed.

Comment: Yes, I know. What would be a better approach?

Comment: a lot of those subqueries DON'T have to be subqueries at all, e.g. `max(contractor_pay_umbrella)`.

Comment: So, perform a JOIN on Contractor_Pay, and rewriting the subselect as ***MAX(Contractor_Pay.Date_Earned) AS 'Last_Pay_Date*'** .

Comment: How could I perform a similar thing for the subselects that have their own JOINs and WHERE clauses?

Comment: that's where it gets complicated, and those most likely you should leave as subselects. you CAN try just moving them "up" into the main query and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have each of those as subselects in the FROM clause (with GROUP BY Contractor_ID) then JOIN them up:

```
SELECT
    Contractor.id,
    Contractor.Unique_ID,
    Contractor.FName,
    Contractor.SName,
    Contractor.MIName,
    Contractor.NI_Number,
    Contractor.Address,
    Contractor.Phone_Main,
    Contractor.Phone_Mobile,
    Contractor.Email,
    Contractor.Bank_Name,
    Contractor.Bank_Account_Name,
    Contractor.Bank_Account_Sort_Code,
    Contractor.Bank_Account_Number,
    Contractor.DOB,
    Contractors.DateTime_Account_Created,
    Contractor.Payment_Frequency,
    Contractor.Saving_Tax_Pref,
    Contractor.Holiday_Savings_Pref,
    Contractor.UTR,
    Contractor.DateTime_Last_Logged_In,
    Contractor.Leaving_Date,
    Agency.Name,
    Tax_Saving_Balance.val as Tax_Saving_Balance,
    Holiday_Saving_Balance.val as Holiday_Saving_Balance,
    Expenses_Claimed.val as Expenses_Claimed,
    Expenses_Authorised.val as Expenses_Authorised,
    Last_Pay_Date.val as Last_Pay_Date
FROM Contractor
LEFT JOIN Agency ON Agency.id = Contractor.Agency_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SavingsToPayJunction.ContractorId, ROUND(SUM(ContractorSavings.value - ContractorSavings.paidOutValue), 2) as val,
    FROM ContractorSavings
    LEFT JOIN SavingsToPayJunction ON SavingsToPayJunction.SavingsId = ContractorSavings.id
    WHERE fullyPaid = 0
    AND ContractorSavings.type_id = 2
    GROUP BY SavingsToPayJunction.ContractorId
) as Tax_Saving_Balance ON Tax_Saving_Balance.ContractorId = Contractor.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SavingsToPayJunction.ContractorId, ROUND(SUM(ContractorSavings.value - ContractorSavings.paidOutValue), 2) as val
    FROM ContractorSavings
    LEFT JOIN SavingsToPayJunction ON SavingsToPayJunction.SavingsId = ContractorSavings.id
    WHERE fullyPaid = 0
    AND ContractorSavings.type_id = 2
    GROUP BY SavingsToPayJunction.ContractorId
) as Holiday_Saving_Balance ON Holiday_Saving_Balance.ContractorId = Contractor.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Contractor_ID, ROUND(SUM(Expense_Value),2) as val
    FROM Contractor_Expenses
    WHERE authorised = 0
    GROUP BY Contractor_ID
) as Expenses_Claimed ON Expenses_Claimed.Contractor_ID = Contractor.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Contractor_ID, ROUND(SUM(Expense_Value - amountAllocated),2) as val
    FROM Contractor_Expenses
    WHERE authorised = 1
    AND fullyAllocated = 0
    GROUP BY Contractor_ID
) as Expenses_Authorised ON Expenses_Authorised.Contractor_ID = Contractor.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Contractor_ID, MAX(Contractor_Pay.Date_Earned)
    FROM Contractor_Pay
    GROUP BY Contractor_ID
) as Last_Pay_Date ON Last_Pay_Date.Contractor_ID = Contractor.Unique_ID
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, the approach in your answer is actually faster than my current query.

Out of interest, do you know why it is faster?

Comment: The subqueries in the FROM clause are run only once (non correlated) - in your query they are simpler but run once per contractor. In MySQL an indexed JOIN is faster than a correlated subquery, and temporary tables in subqueries get automatic indexes for the fields that need them (as of 5.6 I think).